# rtl871xdrv driver not working

Tags: networking, wireless-adapter

So I'm trying to get hostAPD to run on my raspberry pi and after a full day of trying and researching, I'm just gonna ask the question here.

When trying to start hostAPD, it displays the message

```
configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
drv->ifindex=3
12_sock_recv==12_sock_xmit=0x0x8b5648
ioctl[SIOCSIWMODE]: invalid argument
Could not set interface to mode(3)!
Could not set interface to master model
rtl871xdrv driver initialization failed
```

Really annoying that people make programs that don't work/don't have any documentation on how to make it work.

I'd really like to connect wirelessly to my RPi. I don't even need it to redirect an internet connection, I just want to connect to it as if being a router.

Some help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you checked with ifconfig -a that you see wlan0 or wlan1 - the WiFi module.

Comment: See this page before? see: setup __IPTables__ and __DHCP server__ , etc... https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into your question. Instead cut and paste it into an answer and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer finishes the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved. The cause is that hostapd felt the need to change the standard driver for some reason that is far, far beyond me. My wireless adapter only works with the nl80211 driver. To install this, you need the source code for hostapd and change the .config file to support this driver, after/before that, you need to install the driver with `sudo apt install libnl-dev`. Then, it's time to compile and everything should be working